C# Hiding a form with button click
I want to hide my Loadingscreen form when I press the Play button to play my little game, but there came an error on my screen saying "An object is required for the non-static field, method, or property'Control.hide()'.
I don't know how to fix it.
Here is the code
private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Form1 f2 = new Form1();
     f2.Show();

     IntroScreen.Hide();
 }


It's hard to fix your code without seeing it. Please read [ask] and [edit] your post with a [mre].

It sounds like you're trying to call a method on a class rather than on an object instance of that class.  Call the method on an object instance instead?

The error "An object is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Control.Hide()'" indicates that you're trying to call the Hide method on a class rather than an instance of the form or control.
In your case, IntroScreen should be an instance of the form or control that you want to hide.
Assuming IntroScreen is the current form that contains the btnPlay button, you could use this.Hide() to hide it.
private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 f2 = new Form1();
    f2.Show();

    // Hide the current form (assuming this is IntroScreen)
    this.Hide();
}

If IntroScreen is another form, your code might look like this:
private IntroScreen introScreen; // Field to store the instance of IntroScreen

public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    introScreen = new IntroScreen(); // Initialize the IntroScreen instance
    introScreen.Show(); // Show the IntroScreen initially
}

private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 f2 = new Form1();
    f2.Show();
    // Hide the IntroScreen form
    introScreen.Hide();
}

Use this.Hide() if you want to hide the current form.
Ensure you are referencing an instance of the form or control you want to hide, not the class itself.
Initialize and store instances of forms or controls you need to interact with later.

It looks like you are new to object-oriented programming, so you have to first understand how classes work.
C# is object-oriented programming language. A class is like a food recipe. Imagine you have a cake recipe. You use that to make a cake. You don't consume (eat) the recipe, you eat the cake made by that recipe.
Similarly, in C# sharp, you don't consume the class methods and properties unless if they are static. You use the methods of properties of objects created by that class.
Let's say we have a class called Car, and it has a method called Drive. We have to first create an object from the Car class, then be able to call the Drive method:
class Car
{
    public void Drive()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Car is driving.");
    }
}

var carObject = new Car();

// This works because we call the Drive method on an instance of Car class.
carObject.Drive();

// This will not compile because we call the Drive method on the Class directly, and the Drive method is NOT static.
Car.Drive();

So you have to call the Hide method of an object created from the IntroScreen class, not the class itself.
It's not clear what class the btnPlay_Click method is in from your example. I assume it's inside the IntroScreen class. If so, then you just have to change it to the following:
private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Form1 f2 = new Form1();
     f2.Show();

     // Instead of calling IntroScreen.Hide(), we call Hide() 
     // which means call the Hide method on the current instance of the IntroScreen class.
     Hide();
}

